# how to do something in all slides by just one code?

Tags: vba

i use this code and you can see it just work for slide 1  :

```
 Sub o_c_LTab(shape As shape)

Lt = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("LT").Left
If Lt = -175 Then
    Do
    DoEvents
    Lt = Lt + 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("LT").Left = Lt
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("LT_handle").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("LT_handle").Left + 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("1").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("1").Left + 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("2").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("2").Left + 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("3").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("3").Left + 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("4").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("4").Left + 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("5").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("5").Left + 25

    timeout (0.01)
    Loop Until Lt = 0
ElseIf Lt = 0 Then
    Do
    DoEvents
    Lt = Lt - 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("LT").Left = Lt
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("LT_handle").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("LT_handle").Left - 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("1").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("1").Left - 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("2").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("2").Left - 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("3").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("3").Left - 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("4").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("4").Left - 25
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("5").Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("5").Left - 25
    timeout (0.01)
    Loop Until Lt = -175
End If

End Sub


Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= duration_ms
End Sub
```

i have this shapes in 200 slides and i should write this for 200 times , how can i do that in all slides by just one code?

Comment: Why don't do a loop? Instead of `.Slide(1)` put `Slide(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `Slide` will be an item in the `Slides` collection.
You can step through each item in a collection using:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sl As Slide

    For Each sl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Debug.Print sl.Name
    Next sl

End Sub
```

Then rather than use `ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("LT")` you can use `sl.Shapes("LT")`